# Multiple optional parameters with angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use multiple optional parameters with ui-router but it does not seem to work. Below are the tests i did:

Single parameter is OK

```
state.url       url called     state param values

/page/:x        /page/         $stateParams.x == ""
/page/:x        /page/2        $stateParams.x == "2"
```

One optional parameter is OK

```
/page/:x?       /page/         $stateParams.x == ""
/page/:x?       /page/2        $stateParams.x == "2"
```

Two parameters are OK (except the ugly double slashes in first case, `/page` and `/page/` turn into `/page//`. But since the parameters are not optional that's OK)

```
/page/:x/:y     /page//        $stateParams.x == "" && $stateParams.y == ""
/page/:x/:y     /page/2        $stateParams.x == "" && $stateParams.y == ""
/page/:x/:y     /page/2/       $stateParams.x == "2" && $stateParams.y == ""
/page/:x/:y     /page/2/3      $stateParams.x == "2" && $stateParams.y == "3"
```

Two optional parameters behaves strange. Second parameters is always undefined and it cannot solve first parameter when I specify the second one.

```
/page/:x?/:y?   /page/         $stateParams.x == "" && $stateParams.y == undefined
/page/:x?/:y?   /page/2        $stateParams.x == "2" && $stateParams.y == undefined
/page/:x?/:y?   /page/2/       $stateParams.x == "" && $stateParams.y == undefined
/page/:x?/:y?   /page/2/3      $stateParams.x == "" && $stateParams.y == undefined
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

UI-Router optional parameter are not specified by modifying the URL.  Rather, they are specified using the `params` object in the state definition.

The declaration `url: '/page/:x?/:y?'` does not mark x and y as optional parameters.  Instead, the question mark is used to separate the URL and Query Param portion of the URL.

Read the description text in the [UrlMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher) docs and the [$stateProvider.state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) docs for `url`, then for `params`.

You will end up with optional params configured like so:

```
$stateProvider.state('page', {
  url: '/page/:x/:y',
  params: { 
    x: 5,  // default value of x is 5
    y: 100 // default value of y is 100
  }
})
```

Comment: This is a good answer simply for not just saying to use query parameters like I expected people would.

Comment: For me, it pops a "Error: Both params and url specicified in state 'page'" error.

Comment: And when I read this error, I think: "Error: 'ci' specified twice in 'specicified' ". (your_lol_here)

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent version of ui router